# Does an inversion exist for 0-conditional?

Tags: conditionals

For what I have studied in English there are 4 types of conditionals, sometimes referred to as: 0-conditional, first conditional, second conditional and fourth conditional.

**0-CONDITIONAL**

It is used when the result will always happen, for something that is always true. It is formed with

```
IF+PRESENT SIMPLE, PRESENT SIMPLE
```

For example:

*If water reaches 100 celsius degrees at the sea level, it boils*

This is something always true and generally *if* can be replaced with *when* without changing the meaning.

**FIRST CONDITIONAL**

It is used to talk about thing that might happen in the future. 
The structure is

```
IF+PRESENT SIMPLE, WILL + INFINITIVE
```

For example:

*If it rains, I won't go to the party.*

**Compared to the 0-conditional**, it describes a particular situation. For example consider the two examples:

1. *If you sit in the sun, you get burned.*
2. *If you sit in the sun, you will get burned.*

The first example means every time you sit in the sun. In the second it is meant a particular situation, for example today is a very sunny day.

In more formal English, one can use **inversion in the first conditional** by replacing **IF** with **SHOULD** and using the verb with the **bare infinitive**. For example:

*Should you sit in the sun, you will get burned*.

**SECOND CONDITIONAL**

Its structure is

```
IF+PAST SIMPLE, WOULD+INFINITIVE
```

It is used in two cases:

1. to talk about things in the future that are unlikely to happen. For example:

   *If I met the Queen of England, I would say hello.*;
2. to talk about things in the present that are unrealistic or impossible to happen. For example:
   *If I were you, I would quit smoking.*

The difference between 1 and the first conditional is the point of view. Consider the two examples:

1. *If she studies harder, she'll pass the exam.*
2. *If she studied harder, she would pass the exam.*

In 1 I think she can pass the exam, in 2 I think she won't study and fail the exam.

Also for second conditional we can use inversions:

1. For unlikely things, `IF` is replaced with `WERE+SUBJECT+INFINITIVE`. Using the same example of above:
   *Were I to meet the Queen of England, I would say hello.*
2. For impossible things delete `IF` and invert the subject and the auxiliary. For example:
   *Were I you, I would stop smoking*.

**THIRD CONDITIONAL**
It is used to describe a thing in the past that did not happen and to image the result. The form is `IF+PAST PERFECT, WOULD+HAVE+PAST PARTICIPLE`.
For example

```
*If she had studied, she would have passed the exam*
```

Also this type of conditional allows inversion:

```
*Had she studied, she would have passed the exam*
```

**MY ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I could find a rule for inversions in case of the first, second and third conditional. I do not know if it is possible and in such case how, to use inversion in the 0-conditional.

Does inversion for 0-conditional exist?

Comment: The terminology '1st, second ... conditionals' is by no means universal. Could you just give your suggested 'inversion' and any research you have done? Do you mean 'If 100C is reached by water, it boils'? You'd need 'If a temperature of 100C is reached by water, it boils' to sound natural.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can remove _if_ and invert subject/verb as in, for example, _Were I rich, I would retire_ (2) and _Had I known, I would have told you_ (3)? I'm at a loss to think of any similar inversion in a (1) conditional. Perhaps you could give an example. And neither can I think of an example of inversion of a (0) conditional.

Comment: This seems like a logic question. Of course you can negate or negate the clauses, but it won't have the same validity.
Given A implies B, not A does not imply anything at all, logically.
If you want a simple negation (which would invalidate the logic), you could say "If water doesn't reach 100 celsius degrees, it boils.

Or, if you're asking for inverting the sentence order, that would make total sense: "It boils if the water reaches 100 celsius degrees". This is also logically consistent.

Comment: Nope. If you try to invert that sentence you have to switch the subject and the dummy subject: "Water boils if it reaches 100 Celsius."

Comment: No, English does not have four conditionals; it has hundreds. That’s just a convenient lie we tell people who keep managing, despite all the many hundreds of kinds of conditionals, to keep choosing forms that are illegal.

Comment: If water reaches 100 Celsius degrees at the sea level, it boils. That is a conditional.